# Do Motherboards limit RAM per stick?

Tags: memory

So long story short My Motherboard says that I have the Iona GL8E but CPU-Z says that I have the MSI-2A9C. The Iona MB does not support 8GB sticks but the MSI one does. When I tried to put an 8GB Stick, PC boots but shutdowns after 4/5 seconds. Could I possibly just put the proper BIOS and use the 8GB stick?

Comment: CPU-Z is not identifying your motherboard properly.  Iona GL8E is an OEM motherboard by HP.  Due to it's age and the chipset, the maximum amount of memory that motherboard supports is a maximum amount of 16 GB.

Comment: Any clue where I should download the correct BIOS update If I can?

Comment: @JohhnyJohnny - A bios update isn't going to solve your problem.  Your motherboard does not support more than 16 GB DDR3.  Attempting to apply firmware not designed specifically for your motherboard will result in bricking the motherboard. You will be left with a very bad doorstop  (since it's a motherboard and it's not very heavy)

Comment: What I mean is, the whole problem is about my MB not supporting 8gb sticks, I already accepted that. However, when looking at my System Information I see that my BIOS is outdated, I found the correct BIOS and correct MB (through HP's model finder) but it says that I need Windows 7, since that's a lot to do and I'm lazy, I wonder if I could install the BIOS update with Windows 10?

Comment: the current/newest available for my MB is 6.16, I have 6.15

Comment: It says you need Windows 7 due to the age of the software.  The amount of software that can run only on Windows 7 and not Windows 10 is extremely small.  In the case of the firmware utility, it supports Windows.  Unless the firmware specifically indicates a problem was solved, that you are currently experiencing, you don't really gain anything from updating the firmware.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think CPU-Z has a problem cause when you take a look at [link] https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-pro-3130-minitower-pc/4191693/model/4191696?sku=BZ718AV under the BIOS tab, you will see something like "HP Compaq Business Desktop ROMPaq Firmware (ROM Family 2A9C-B)" any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.  Generally speaking a BIOS has no control over the amount and size of RAM a computer can use.  That is limited by the memory controller on the motherboard or the CPU itself.  Next, is the motherboard.  While CPU-Z says you have a MSI-2A9C, it is not a MSI motherboard.  It is a motherboard manufactured for HP by MSI.  While the motherboard *might* be based on an existing MSI motherboard, it's specifications are most probably different than any MSI motherboard.

Comment: "a BIOS has no control over the amount and size of RAM a computer can use." actually HP does this all the time.